# Create a forecast matrix from time series samples

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, memory-optimization

I would like to create a matrix of delay from a time series.

For example, given

```
y = [y_0, y_1, y_2, ..., y_N] and W = 5
```

I need to create this matrix:

```
| 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0   |
| 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | y_0 |
| 0       | 0       | 0       | y_0     | y_1 |
| ...     |         |         |         |     |
| y_{N-4} | y_{N-3} | y_{N-2} | y_{N-1} | y_N |
```

I know that function `timeseries_dataset_from_array` from TensorFlow does approximatively the same thing when well configured, but I would like to avoid using TensorFlow.

---

This is my current function to perform this task:

```py
def get_warm_up_matrix(_data: ndarray, W: int) -> ndarray:
    """
    Return a warm-up matrix
    If _data = [y_1, y_2, ..., y_N]
    The output matrix W will be
    W =     +---------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
            | 0       | ... | 0       | 0       | 0   |
            | 0       | ... | 0       | 0       | y_1 |
            | 0       | ... | 0       | y_1     | y_2 |
            | ...     | ... | ...     | ...     | ... |
            | y_1     | ... | y_{W-2} | y_{W-1} | y_W |
            | ...     | ... | ...     | ...     | ... |
            | y_{N-W} | ... | y_{N-2} | y_{N-1} | y_N |
            +---------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
    :param _data:
    :param W:
    :return:
    """
    N = len(_data)

    warm_up = np.zeros((N, W), dtype=_data.dtype)
    raw_data_with_zeros = np.concatenate((np.zeros(W, dtype=_data.dtype), _data), dtype=_data.dtype)

    for k in range(W, N + W):
        warm_up[k - W, :] = raw_data_with_zeros[k - W:k]

    return warm_up
```

It works well, but it's quite slow since the `concatenate` operation and the `for` loop take time to be performed. It also takes a lot of memory since the data have to be duplicated in memory before filling the matrix.

Can I make it faster and more memory-friendly?

Comment: In C++, we would use a `std::ranges::slide_view` for this (with a `take_view` to limit it to `W` rows).  I don't know NumPy well enough, but does it have a concept of views like C++ does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Numpy already has a [built-in sliding window method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view) (though it's perhaps a little obscure). This should indeed be memory-friendly, occupying about (W + N) and not W(W + N) due to it being a view.

Also, about your own code: don't underscore `_data` and don't capitalise `w`. Delete the boilerplate section of your docstring, and prefix `ndarray` with `np` in your typehints.

### Suggested

```
import numpy as np


def get_warm_up_matrix(data: np.ndarray, w: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Return a warm-up matrix
    If data = [y_1, y_2, ..., y_N]
    The output matrix W will be
    W = +---------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
        | 0       | ... | 0       | 0       | 0   |
        | 0       | ... | 0       | 0       | y_1 |
        | 0       | ... | 0       | y_1     | y_2 |
        | ...     | ... | ...     | ...     | ... |
        | y_1     | ... | y_{W-2} | y_{W-1} | y_W |
        | ...     | ... | ...     | ...     | ... |
        | y_{N-W} | ... | y_{N-2} | y_{N-1} | y_N |
        +---------+-----+---------+---------+-----+
    """
    padded = np.zeros(shape=len(data) + w, dtype=data.dtype)
    padded[w:] = data
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(x=padded, window_shape=w)


print(get_warm_up_matrix(data=np.arange(1, 11), w=4))
```

### Output

```
[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1]
 [ 0  0  1  2]
 [ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 2  3  4  5]
 [ 3  4  5  6]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 6  7  8  9]
 [ 7  8  9 10]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and the suggestions !

Comment: For people wondering, the proposed code by @Reinderien is about 24 times faster than mine.